# How to open a link on new tab in GitLab using Ctrl+click

Tags: gitlab

If I use the regular way of opening links on a new tab by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking in GitLab, then the current window opens the link as well. Why? How should I achieve opening links on a new tab in GitLab? If I right-click and choose open link in a new tab then it works but that is slower than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking.

Comment: did you try scroolbutton click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because "they" (aka the person/people that wrote the code) put some code in the webpage to handle the clicks that seems to not care about the state the ctrl-button is in.

How now? user0's suggestion, scrollbuton-clicking worked for me. So I guess I'll have to relearn my habit of ctrl+clicking.